# Working with Java database

Tags: java, database, nullpointerexception, connection

I'm creating a java program which requires a user to provide login details before gaining access. i'm working with a javaDB which i stored the data in a table named LOGIN_DETAILS, i have a successful connection but the problem is whenever i run the program i get this error:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at Classes.Login.bActionPerformed(Login.java:188)
```

and **login.java:188** code is: `Statement st = con.createStatement();`

Below is my complete code;

```
    public void connect(){
        try{
        String host = "jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/db1";
        String uName = "";
        String uPass = "";
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(host, uName, uPass);

        }

        catch(SQLException ex){
    }

}

    try{

    Statement st = con.createStatement();
    Menu MM = new Menu();
    String user = t.getText().trim();
    String pass = t1.getText().trim();

    String sql = "SELECT USERNAME, PASSWORD FROM "
            + "APP.LOGIN_DETAILS WHERE "
            + "USERNAME ='"+user+"'PASSWORD ='"+pass+"'";
    ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(sql);

    int count = 0;
    while(rs.next()){
        count = count + 1;
    }

    if(count ==1){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "User Found, Access Granted");
    this.dispose();
    MM.setVisible(true);
    }

    else if(count > 1){
    JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Duplicate User, Access Denied");
    this.setVisible(true);
    }
    else{
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"User not Found");
    this.setVisible(true);
    }
    }

    catch(SQLException | HeadlessException ex){
    }
```

Please help me in resolving the problem, thank you.

Comment: Your code snippet does not provide the context that we require to fully ascertain what the problem might be.  Needless to say, `con` is likely `null`, you need to figure out why...

Comment: Where is `con` defined?

Answer (score 1):

Unless this bit of code appears elsewhere, it appears that you have not called the connect() method (which sets up the connection) before calling createStatement() on con. Thus, con likely still points to null at that point. If that's the case, it would explain the exception.

Answer (score 0):

`con` is very likely to be null in this situation properbably due to `connect()` not being called.  Although, maybe `connect()` is being called and there is a `SQLException` exception which is silently being caught. In most cases, it is a bad idea to catch an exception and do nothing about it.  Minimally, you should `log the exception`.

Also this is incorrect

```
String sql = "SELECT USERNAME, PASSWORD FROM "
        + "APP.LOGIN_DETAILS WHERE "
        + "USERNAME ='"+user+"'PASSWORD ='"+pass+"'";
```

try

```
String sql = "SELECT USERNAME, PASSWORD FROM "
        + "APP.LOGIN_DETAILS WHERE "
        + "USERNAME = '" +user+ " and 'PASSWORD ='"+pass+"'";
```

Comment: i modified the code but now when i enter the login details and press enter, nothing happens, i am now confused.

Comment: **log your exceptions** - I have also updated my answer

Comment: i'm still getting an exception, i have checked the code and still cant find any potential problem, by the way can you please help me with logging the exception, seriously i dont know how to do so. thanks

Comment: when ever you have code like `catch (..Exception e) {` then add `e.printStackTrace();`  When you have some output, then post it in your answer

Comment: i added ex.printStackTrace(); but here is the error i'm getting when i run the program.          java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Syntax error: Encountered "UPASS" at line 1, column 61.
 at org.apache.derby.client.am.SQLExceptionFactory40.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
 at org.apache.derby.client.am.SqlException.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
 at org.apache.derby.client.am.Statement.executeQuery(Unknown Source)

Comment: Please post you full stack trace in **your** code and **indicate** where the exception (which Line) is being thrown.